# what preposition should I use for "tutorial" for what situation?

Tags: prepositions

I used the preposition "on" for the word "tutorial" in this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/236004/103381)

> This post gives a tutorial on folding a paper box, which uses a term head wall in step3 of part2.

alghough I am not sure I use the preposition correctly.

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutorial) gives this explanantion about "tutorial".

> Internet computer tutorials can take the form of a screen recording (screencast), a written document (either online or downloadable), interactive tutorial, or an audio file, where a person will give step by step instructions **on** how to do something.

where the preposition is used for a synonym, that is, instruction.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tutorial) gives this example

> An online tutorial for the program is available on our website.

while it seems to be strange to say like this

An online tutorial **for** using java to build a E-commerce system.

## question

what preposition should I use for "tutorial" for what situation?

Comment: Both prepositions are possible. For example, “She has given a tutorial **on** Aussie slang for non-Australians” and “I went to a tutorial **for** building regression analysis.”  I prefer the preposition “on” here but others may disagree.

Comment: *On* is the most common. But *for*, *in*, *of*, and *about* are also in use.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Is it still clear and idimatic if I substitute "for" for "on" in your 1st example so that, "She has given a tutorial **for** Aussie slang for non-Australians"?

Comment: @user105719 Is it still clear and idimatic if I substitute "on" for "for" in the cambridge example so that, "An online tutorial **on** the program is available on our website."

Comment: It's  idiomatic ("on" is acceptable for the topic of the tutorial), but it's not entirely clear because "on the program" also means "during the broadcast of a program." The context will likely make it clear which one is meant, but it's inadvisable to force your reader to make the decision.

Comment: @user105719. I can almost see what you mean if it were a sentence about a broadcast program - but it’s not. The natural reading of this sentence (even in isolation, with no context) is surely with “program” in the sense of software. I personally don’t perceive the lack of clarity that you perceive when “tutorial on the program” is used.